# Token Ignore some elements in the String

Tags: c, token

I am trying to implement a project to read Hexadecimal number and sort it. The code with working with me correctly when I hard written the input inside the code, but when I modified the code to take the input from text file instead I got incorrect results and when I debugged the code I found that the token didn't get all the values and I can't figure out why.

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{


    FILE *in_file  = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *out_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");


    int bufferLength = 255;
    char buffer[bufferLength];

      if (in_file == NULL)
    {
      printf("Error! Could not open file\n");
      exit(-1);
    }

    char input[] = {};

    fgets(input, bufferLength, in_file);


    int decimal[1000] = {0};

    char * token = strtok(input, " ");
    int n = (int) strtol(token, NULL, 16);
    decimal[0] = n;

    printf("N is : %d , token is : %s \n", n, token);

    int no = 0;
    while(token != NULL) {
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      int n = (int) strtol(token, NULL, 16);
      decimal[no+1] = n;
      no++;
      printf("N is : %d , token is : %s \n", n, token);
   }


int temp = 0;

    //Sort the array
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        if (decimal[i] == 0){
            break;
        }
        for (int j = i+1; j < no; j++) {
           if(decimal[i] > decimal[j]) {
               temp = decimal[i];
               decimal[i] = decimal[j];
               decimal[j] = temp;
           }
        }
    }



    //Print elements
    for (int j = 0; j < no; j++){
        fprintf(out_file,"%X ", decimal[j]);
    }


    fclose(in_file);
    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Input is: 10 A B 1, but when debugging the code I got the following results:

```
N is : 16 , token is : 10
N is : 10 , token is : A

N is : 0 , token is : (null)
```

Comment: Please  [edit] and show a properly formatted minimal version of your input.txt file. Along with the expected vs actual output.

Comment: `char input[] = {};` the `input` array has a fixed length of zero which does not ma make sens. You want `char input[bufferLength] = {0};`. There may be other problems though.

Comment: `printf("Error! Could not open file\n");` is the canonical example of a useless error message. Try `perror("input.txt");`

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two problems in your code:

1. `char input[] = {};` declares an array of size zero. When you use `fgets(input, ....)` you'll write beyond the end of this array which will result in undefined behaviour.
2. after `token = strtok(NULL, " ")`, `token` will be `NULL` once there are no more tokens and then you dereference this NULL pointer here: `strtol(token, NULL, 16);`.

So you need to change:

```
char input[] = {};
```

to

```
char input[bufferLength] = {0};
```

and you need to check if `strtok` returns NULL:

```
  while (1) {   //<< change this (loop forever)
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    if (token == NULL)  // << add this
      break;            // << add this

    int n = (int)strtol(token, NULL, 16);
    decimal[no + 1] = n;
    no++;
    printf("N is : %d , token is : %s \n", n, token);
  }
```

**Disclaimer:** there may be problems with the sorting part, I didn't check this.

**Bonus:**

You can replace this:

```
 while (1) {   //<< change this (loop forever)
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    if (token == NULL)  // << add this
      break;            // << add this
```

with this somewhat shorter code:

```
 while ((token = strtok(NULL, " ") != NULL)   
 {
```

but I'm not sure if this is advisable for beginners...

Comment: changing the declaration of the array to what you said threw the error "Variable-size object may not be initialized"

Comment: @MostafaKhaled There's no need for the initialization.  Just write `char input[bufferLength];`

Comment: ... or, just use `buffer`, which seems to have been intended to be used for the input.